# WinError 193 %1 is not a valid Win32 application. az bicep

Tags: python, azure, azure-cli, azure-bicep

When I try to run `az bicep version` I'm getting this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nskW.png)

```
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 233, in invoke
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 664, in execute
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 729, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 698, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 334, in __call__
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/resource/custom.py", line 4601, in show_bicep_cli_version
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/resource/_bicep.py", line 94, in run_bicep_command
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/resource/_bicep.py", line 267, in _get_bicep_installed_version
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/resource/_bicep.py", line 305, in _run_command
  File "subprocess.py", line 548, in run
  File "subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

And the same error I have running all `az bicep ***` commands.

I tried to reinstall azure cli. Did not help.
I deleted py related paths from PATH env variables. That was a suggestion from some github issue page.

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: Sure! Adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of your error is that the bicep executable installed by Azure CLI is corrupted. See [Issue #2364](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/2364) on their repository.

As described in this [comment](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/2364#issuecomment-825049091) you can clean up the `%USERPROFILE\.azure\bin` directory and run `az bicep install` to get it working.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the bicep executable was corrupted, moreover the size if the file was 0 KB .-. Anyway, thank you, that was a solution for me!